# Firestore / Security Rule / Function / Fieldname as Parameter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I would like to have a firestore security rules function I can use to check wheter or not incoming data to a particular document field (`request.resource.data.<some_field_name>`) is of a certain type e.g. `string`.

## Use Case Explained via simple Example

For a particular field called `firstName` it can easily be done like this:

```
rules_version = '2'
service cloud.firestore {
    match /users/{uid} {
        allow read
        allow write: if isString()
      }
}

function isString() { return request.resource.data.firstName is string }
```

## What works in Practice but isn't practical

However, I would have to hardcode `firstName` inside the function so the function isn't generic i.e. if I wanted to also check whether or not another field on this document e.g. `lastName` is of type `string` I'd have to have the basically same function again except this time I'd hardcode `lastName`:
`function isString() { return request.resource.data.lastName is string }` then rename the functions accordingly so I end up with something like this:

```
rules_version = '2'
service cloud.firestore {
    match /users/{uid} {
        allow read
        allow write: if firstNameisString() || lastNameisString()
      }
}

function firstNameisString() { return request.resource.data.firstName is string }
function lastNameisString() { return request.resource.data.lastName is string }
```

## What I want to do

but what I really want is something where I could **provide the `fieldName` as a parameter** so I could do this, thereby not having to duplicate code for every fieldName I'd like to validate but really just have one function for n fieldNames:

```
rules_version = '2'
service cloud.firestore {
    match /users/{uid} {
        allow read
        allow write: if isString(fieldName)
      }
}

function isString(fieldName) { return request.resource.data.fieldName is string }
```

Am I missing something really obvious or why isn't that syntax possible as the firebase console or the rules emulator isn't allowing it?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Resource#data), resource.data has type rules.Map, which you can access with the [] operator or the get method:

```
function isString(fieldName) { 
    return request.resource.data[fieldName] is string;
}
```

Comment: Great answer Louis! It helps to realize that security rules a broad subset of JavaScript, so here you're [using bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) to allow a dynamic field name.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent, thanks much, that worked, I used it like so

```
match /public/{uid} {
        allow read
        allow write: if isString('userProfession')
      }
```

i.e. the fieldName is a string thus in single quotes.